# Adding Hover/Focus effects to GridView Table Sortable Headers

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview, hover, focus

I'm trying to add hover and focus effects (changing color) to GridView sortable headers.

I'm able to get the non-sortable headers to have hover effects, but not the the sortable headers via HeaderStyle.

I've also tried adding ItemStyle-CssClass to the BoundField to no avail.

Comment: Please provide code examples so that people can assist you.

Comment: If a GridView is sortable the headers become hyperlinks. Maybe that is the issue.